# Component in React Native wrongly rendered after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm having a really weird problem with my React Native component. Component's state is correctly updated, but it is not reflected on what is rendered by the component.

Here is what my component looks like (I didn't include imports and other parts of the code that are irrelevant):

```js
export default function MessageActionsModal({ 
  message,
  actions,
  onClose
}) {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(null);
  const [messageActions, setMessageActions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message !== null) {
      setMessageActions(actions.map((a) => ({
        ...a,
        onPress: () => {
          a.onPress(message?.item);
          onClose();
        }
      })))
    } else {
      setMessageActions([]);
    }
  }, [message, actions, onClose]);
  
  if (message === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Portal>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.messageActionsModal}
        activeOpacity={0}
        onPress={onClose}
      >
        <Portal style={styles.messageActionsModalInnerContainer}>
          <MessageListItem
            style={[
              styles.message,
              getMessagePositionAndDimensions(message)
            ]}
            {...message.item}
          />
          <View
            style={[
              styles.messageActionsMenu,
              getMenuPosition(dimensions, message)
            ]}
            {...dimensions === null && {
              onLayout: ({ nativeEvent }) => setDimensions({
                width: nativeEvent.layout.width,
                height: nativeEvent.layout.height
              })
            }}
          >
            <Text>{'LEN'}{messageActions.length}</Text>
            <Text>{'LOG'}{console.log(messageActions.length)}</Text>

            {messageActions.map((a) => (
              <Button
                key={a.title}
                style={styles.messageActionButton}
                title={a.title}
                variant="text"
                startIcon={a.icon}
                startIconProps={{
                  style: styles.messageActionButtonIconWrapper,
                  iconStyle: styles.messageActionButtonIcon,
                  fill: Colors.yellow
                }}
                onPress={a.onPress}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        </Portal>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Portal>
  );
}
```

So basically, after `messageActions` are updated in the `useEffect`, component renders incorrectly and neither message action is rendered (although one item should be rendered).

Another interesting thing is that the following code renders "LEN 0", but it logs "LOG 1" in the console.

```js
<Text>{'LEN'}{messageActions.length}</Text>
<Text>{'LOG'}{console.log(messageActions.length)}</Text>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: any working example? any expo snack? will check there

Comment: @GauravRoy I will add that during during the day.

Comment: @GauravRoy sorry, didn't have time to work on this one. I will tag you when I create expo snack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try memoizing actions instead of using `useEffect`. Here's an example:

```js
const messageActions = useMemo(() => {
    if (message === null) {
      return [];
    }
    
    return actions.map((a) => ({
        ...a,
        onPress: () => {
          a.onPress(message?.item);
          onClose();
        }
    }));
}, [message, actions, onClose]);
```

Comment: That indeed works! Thank you!